# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, contest-math

> Let $a_1,\cdots, a_{2022}$ be real numbers in $(0,1)$. Define for $n\ge 2023$, $a_n = (a_{n-1}+\cdots + a_{n-2022})^{1/2023}$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists.

Clearly it suffices to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n^{2023}$ exists since $x\mapsto x^{1/2023}$ is a continuous function (on $\mathbb{R}$). I initially thought of using the Cesaro stolz theorem, but it seems hard to prove that the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}^{2023}-a_n^{2023}}{1} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n - a_{n-2022}$ exists. But  it should be possible to prove it indeed exists and is equal to zero. The Squeeze theorem or some sort of telescoping sum might help. I'm not sure if inequalities like the AM-GM inequality could be useful for this problem.

Comment: I think it's possible to show that the sequence is monotone increasing after the first 2022 entries, in which case showing that it's bounded above would be the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the beginning of the sequence, where $n \leq 2022.$ Due to monotonicity, we have that $a_n < 1$ implies $a_n^{2022/2023} < 1,$ and because $a_n > 0$ implies $a_n^{1/2023} > 0,$ multiplying on both sides we have that $a_n < a_n^{1/2023}$ for all $n \leq 2022.$ We must also have that $a_n < \sum_{k = 1}^{2022} a_k,$ due to $a_n > 0$ for $n \leq 2022,$ so $$a_n < a_n^{1/2023} < \left(\sum_{k = 1}^{2022} a_k\right)^{1/2023} = a_{2023}$$

Now note that when we calculate $a_{2024},$ this new value $a_{2023}$ will replace $a_1$ in the sum inside the power, leading to an even larger result. This leads us to the following statement:

> For all integers $n \geq 2023, a_n > a_{n-1}.$ (or, $a$ is monotone increasing for $n > 2022$)

We will prove this by strong induction: our statement above shows that this is true for the base case $n = 2023.$

Now supposing that we have $a_n > a_{n-1}$ for all $2023 \leq n < k,$ we want to prove it true for $n = k.$

It will help to show that $a_{k-1} > a_{k - 2023}$: if $k \geq 4045$ then $k - 2023 \geq 2022$ and the desired inequality drops out from simply repeatedly applying the inequality $a_n > a_{n-1}$. Otherwise, for $2023 < k < 4045$ we still have $a_{k-1} \geq a_{2023},$ and because $k - 2023 < 2022$ we have $a_{2023} > a_{k - 2023}$ by our earlier work, so $a_{k-1} > a_{k - 2023}.$

Recall that by definition we have $$a_k = \left(\sum_{m = k-2022}^{k-1} a_m\right)^{1/2023}, \ \ \  a_{k-1} = \left(\sum_{m = k-2023}^{k-2} a_m\right)^{1/2023}$$ Rewriting inside the power in the first equation we get $$a_k = \left(\sum_{m = k-2023}^{k-2} a_m + (a_{k-1} - a_{k-2023})\right)^{1/2023}$$

and because $a_{k-1} > a_{k-2023}, a_{k-1} - a_{k-2023} > 0 $ and consequently $$\sum_{m = k-2023}^{k-2} a_m + (a_{k-1} - a_{k-2023}) > \sum_{m = k-2023}^{k-2} a_m$$

and again by the monotonicity of the power function here this yields

$$\left(\sum_{m = k-2023}^{k-2} a_m + (a_{k-1} - a_{k-2023})\right)^{1/2023} > \left(\sum_{m = k-2023}^{k-2} a_m\right)^{1/2023} \\ \therefore a_k > a_{k-1}$$

concluding the proof.

---

This nearly concludes the proof that $a_n$ converges. All that remains is to show that $a$ is bounded above, which is rather simple: let's choose $a_n < 2.$

It's clear that this bound holds for $n \leq 2022,$ since we have $a_n < 1$ there. For $n \geq 2023,$ we will again continue using strong induction: suppose that $a_n < 2$ is true for all $n < k.$ Naturally,

$$\sum_{m = k-2022}^{k-1} a_m < \sum_{m = k-2022}^{k-1} 2 = 4044 < 2^{2023} \\
a_k = \left(\sum_{m = k-2022}^{k-1} a_m\right)^{1/2023} < \left(2^{2023}\right)^{1/2023} = 2$$

proving that $a_n < 2$ for all natural numbers $n,$ and because $a_n$ is both monotonically increasing and bounded above, it must converge.

---

I hope this helps. Sorry if any of the writing got a bit gnarly, I've tried to keep everything as readable as possible but it can be tough with all the $2022$s and $2023$s going around. (My apologies in advance as well for any minor errors, there were a few picky details I had to go back and forth on a bit so I could have missed something.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_n=a_{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-2022}$ for $n\ge 2023$.
First, notice that $a_n>0$ for all $n$, shown by induction.
Assume that $a_n<1$ for all $n$. Then for $n\ge 2023$ we have $a_n>a_n^{2023}=S_n>\max_{i=1,\dots,2022}a_{n-i}$, so with induction we obtain that $a_n$ is strictly increasing for $n\ge 2023$, hence it converges.
Otherwise, let $n_\circ$ be the smallest integer with $a_{n_\circ}\ge 1$, in particular $n_\circ\ge 2023$.

With induction we get $S_n>1$ and hence $a_n>1$ for $n\ge n_\circ$.
Let $n_*=n_\circ+2022$. For $n_\circ\le n<n_*$ we have
$a_{n}>1>a_{n-2022}$, so $S_{n+1}-S_{n}=a_{n}-a_{n-2022}>0$ and further $a_{n+1}=S_{n+1}^{1/2023}>S_{n}^{1/2023}=a_{n}$, which gives $a_{n}>a_k$ for $k<n$ and $n_\circ\le n\le n_*$. The same induction gives $a_n>a_k$ for $k<n$ and $n_\circ\le n$, since we have $a_n>a_{n-2022}$ in the induction step directly from the induction hypothesis. Hence, the sequence is eventually strictly increasing and converges.

Notice that in any case the sequence is strictly increasing for $n\ge 2023$, as pointed out by Stephen in the comment.
In order to identify fixed points of the recursion consider the solutions of the equation $x=(2022x)^{1/2023}$ for $x>0$, which are exactly the roots of
$f(x)=x-(2022x)^{1/2023}=x^{1/2023}(x^{2022/2023}-2022^{1/2023})$. Thus, we clearly have a unique root at $a_*=2022^{1/2022}>1$.
Since the initial elements are smaller than $1$ and $a_*>1$, we use induction to obtain $a_n<(2022 a_*)^{1/2023}=a_*$ for all $n$.

In particular, this yields $a_\circ=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n\le a_*$. Now, for arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$ there exists $n_\circ$ such that $a_\circ-\varepsilon< a_n< a_\circ$ for all $n\ge n_\circ$. Hence, for $n>n_\circ+2022$ we have $a_\circ> a_n>(2022(a_\circ-\varepsilon))^{1/2023}$. Taking $\varepsilon$ to $0$ gives $a_\circ\ge(2022a_\circ)^{1/2023}$ since the right hand side is continuous, i.e. $f(a_\circ)\ge 0$. But the product form of $f$ above immediately yields $f(x)<0$ for $0<x<a_*$ since $x^{2022/2023}$ is increasing. With $a_\circ\le a_*$ this yields $a_\circ=a_*$.
So, the sequences $a_n$ converges to $a_*$ independent of the initial conditions.